# How to resize textarea in cypress

Tags: html, cypress

How to resize the textarea in Cypress.

I'm using `cypress-real-events` plugin to interact with html elements.

I've to resize the textarea and tried below code but its not working.

```
cy.get("textarea").eq(0)
  .realMouseDown({ position: "bottomRight" })
  .realMouseUp({ position: "bottomRight" })
  .realMouseDown({ position: "bottomRight" })
  .realMouseMove(100, 100, { position: "bottomRight" })
  .realMouseUp({ position: "bottomRight" });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the test? It's a browser control, you should not have to test it.

Answer (score 4):

Although I tried yesterday to get a solution using javascript, I could not get any success.

I think that's because the `textarea` is a control that is built into the browser and does not have correct hooks (methods or properties) to affect the sizing of the box.

For example, I used a local HTML file which just has a `<textarea>`. Running local avoids the issues for which puneet had to add `cy.wait(3000)` in between commands.

With this local test, there is no asynchronous element and all the code takes effect immediately.

This is the ***failing*** test which relies on javascript.

```js
cy.visit('/')

const getHeight = ($el) => $el[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;   // helper

cy.get(`textarea`).then(getHeight).as('start')

cy.get(`textarea`) 
  .realHover()
  .realMouseDown({ position: "bottomRight", scrollBehavior: false })
  .realMouseWheel({ deltaY: 100 })
  .realMouseUp({ position: "bottomRight", scrollBehavior: false })

cy.get(`textarea`).then(getHeight).as('end')

cy.get('@start').then(startingHeight => {
  cy.get('@end').should('be.gt', startingHeight)
})
```

[image]

---

#### Passing the test with CSS

The `<textarea>` can be resized with the browser CSS engine instead of javascript.

```js
cy.visit('/');

const getHeight = ($el) => $el[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;   // helper

cy.get(`textarea`).then(getHeight).as('start')

cy.get(`textarea`)
  .then($ta => $ta[0].style.height = '500px')  // use CSS to set the element height

cy.get(`textarea`).then(getHeight).as('end')

cy.get('@start').then(startingHeight => {
  cy.get('@end').should('be.gt', startingHeight)
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded `cypress-real-events` to latest 1.8.1 version and used `realMouseWheel` event to fixed it.

Below is the code:

```
it("textarea resize", () => {
  cy.visit("https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-set-the-size-of-the-textarea-element.html").wait(10000)

  cy.get(`textarea`).eq(0)
        .realHover()
        .wait(3000)
        .realMouseDown({ position: "bottomRight", scrollBehavior: false })
        .wait(3000)
        .realMouseWheel({ deltaY: 100 })
        .wait(3000)
        .realMouseUp({ position: "bottomRight", scrollBehavior: false });
});
```

Comment: It's not actually doing anything on my `textarea`. Do you have a more complete example?

Comment: @Otto what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work.

Comment: I updated  the answer, try it.

Comment: updated answer once again.

Comment: Sadly nothing happens. The height is the same before and after.

Comment: @Otto Code updated. Try it as well. Its all working for me.

Comment: No, it's not working even after very long waits and hovers.

Comment: Why don't you add an assertion to the test and post the Cypress log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254246/discussion-between-puneet18-and-otto).

Comment: I just had an alternative idea, if my test succeeds I will post it for you.

Comment: check this https://uploadnow.io/files/3F3F7r6

Comment: Plus - it does not need any awful `cy.wait(3000)`!

Comment: yes please share if you found any alternate solution. Thanks!

Comment: I added cy.wait(3000) just for delay if somehow it affects at your end. For me, I added wait(1000) and it works fine.

Comment: What are you giving on uploadnow? I can't get to it.

Comment: I tried to upload the screencast to show its working fine

Comment: check https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RlXGYfu9lyiLPTKDXf3BW-wZDzLFVrYM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I saw you had it on Electron, so I changed to that but still no good. Have you figured out an assertion so you are not relying on video and eyeball?

Comment: what assertion should I add on resize textarea?

Comment: I use `const getHeight = ($el) => $el[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;` and in the test `.then(getHeight).as('starting')` and after resize `.then(getHeight).as('ending')`, and finally compare the two values.

Comment: I can achieve it by setting style height to say `500px` but not through Javascript of any kind.